# Partial Sum of Sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series

We have the next sequence: $$\sum_{t=1}^{n}\frac{t^2}{(1+r)^t}$$ The problem is: find the partial sum of the sequence $S_n$.
Should I consider above mentioned sequence as "Arithmetico-Geometric Sequence"?Could someone show me the right way?
Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is $\sum_{t=1}^n t^2x^t$ where $x=1/(1+r)$. Now
$$\sum_{t=1}^n t^2x^t=x\frac d{dx}\sum_{t=1}^n tx^t$$
and
$$\sum_{t=1}^n tx^t=x\frac d{dx}\sum_{t=1}^nx^t$$
etc.

Comment: Is $\frac{d}{dz}$ partial derivative and what you have denoted by $z$?